# window resize issue using jquery

Tags: jquery, facebook, resize, hide, show

Please go through below image
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36614618/Doubts/onlineChatImg.jpg
In the image above 'Image 01' you can find a onlineChat div at the right side of the html document. When I hover on online chat div, we can find a search input and hide online chat button '|>' to the bottom of the online chat. please go through above image 'Image 02'. Now when I click on hide button '|>', onlinechat div is getting hide 'Image 03'. As soon as onlinechat div gets hide, an another icon gets displayed, to showup onlinechat again '|<'. Till now its working fine.
But the issue is, when I resize my window, Onlinechat Div getting displayed automatically. What I am looking for is While window resize, if onlinechat is hidden, then it should be hidden (shouldn't show up).
Above concept is somewhat same as Facebook online chat

```
$('#onlineFriendsSearchShow').hide();// Default Search input is hide.

$('#OnlineChathideShowIcon').on('click',function(){ //When clicked on '|>' button, onlineChat div hide and left part div gets width of 100%.
    $('#rapMusicSocialNetworkRightPart').hide();//onlineChat div getting hide.
    $('#rapMusicSocialNetworkLeftPartWrapper').css('width','100%'); //Left part gets width of 100%.
    $('#onlineFriendsSearchShow').show();//show button '|<' gets displayed.
});

$('#onlineFriendsSearchShow').bind('click',function(){ //When clicked on '|<' show button. (to get right onlineChat div back).
    $(this).hide();//'|<' button hide.
    $('#onlineFriendsSearch').show();//search input show.
    $('#rapMusicSocialNetworkRightPart').show();//onlineChat div show.

    var widthRap = $(window).width()-201;//created variable having mainWindow width - onlineChat Div width.
    $('#rapMusicSocialNetworkLeftPartWrapper').css('width',widthRap);//variable value assigning to left part, so left and right divs get's adjusted within document.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some refresh :

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var widthRap = $(window).width()-201;//created variable having mainWindow width - onlineChat Div width.
    $('#rapMusicSocialNetworkLeftPartWrapper').css('width',widthRap);//variable value assigning to left part, so left and right divs get's adjusted within document.
});
```